# Maximizing $\sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{m=1}^n s_rs_m \cos \frac{2\pi (r - m)}{n}$

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, summation

> For a real $s \geq 1$ and an integer $n > 1$, define real $s_r$ in $0 \leq s_r \leq s$ for $1 \leq r \leq n$. Find the maximum value of the sum
>
> $$S = \sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{m=1}^n s_rs_m \cos \frac{2\pi (r - m)}{n}$$

It may be worth noting that there is a recurrance relation, which helps slightly. Defining

$$S(t) = \sum_{r=1}^t \sum_{m=1}^t s_rs_m\cos\frac{2\pi(r-m)}n,$$

we obtain that

$$S(t+1) = S(t) + s_{t+1}^2 + 2s_{t+1} \sum_{m=1}^t s_r\cos\frac{2\pi(t+1-m)}n.$$

In the special case that each $s_r = s$, I found that the difference $S(t+1) - S(t) < 0$ when

$$s^2\left(1 + 2\sum_{m=1}^t \cos\frac{2\pi (t+1-m)}n \right) \leq 0,$$

or when

$$\sum_{m=1}^t \cos\frac{2\pi (t+1-m)}n = \sum_{m=1}^t \cos\frac{2\pi m}n \leq -\frac12,$$

which through a quick python program and some experimental values, I've found to hold true (without proof) when $\lceil n/2 \rceil < t \leq n$. From this, I'm pretty sure the maximal sum $S$ when each $s_r \in \{s,0\}$ occurs when

$$s_r = \begin{cases}
s & 1 \leq r \leq \lceil n/2 \rceil, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

In the general case, $S(t+1) - S(t) < 0$ would occur when

$$\sum_{m=1}^t s_m\cos\frac{2\pi(t-m)}n < -\frac{s_{t+1}}2,$$

however this sum is trickier to bound due to the weights attached to the cosine sum.

---

**Edit**: Alright, I've tried some of the suggestions, particularly the one by dezdichado, which suggested

$$S = \left( \sum_{r=1}^n s_r \cos\frac{2\pi r}n \right)^2 + \left( \sum_{r=1}^n s_r \sin\frac{2\pi r}n \right)^2, \tag{a}$$

which makes the problem, interestingly, about attempting to maximize the magnitude of the sum of multiples of $n$th roots of unity:

$$S = \left| \sum_{r=1}^n s_r e^{2\pi i r/n} \right|^2, \tag{b}$$

where each $0 \leq s_r \leq s$, for some real $s \geq 1$.

However, trying to bound the sum in the form (a) is proving troublesome, especially since there are two different sums. I have a feeling there is some way to bound $S$ in the form (b), but I don't really see anyway to do it.

Kinda given up on the problem, so any hints and solutions welcome!

Comment: this is to be maximized given $n$ or all $n$ and all $s_r$?

Comment: Over $s_r$, the values $s$ and $n$ are fixed

Answer (score 1):

I think a good start would be to make use of the little trick:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^ns_rs_ma_ra_m = \left(\sum_{r=1}^ns_ra_r\right)^2.$$
So, expand the $\cos$ term and you get two sum of squares like above, since:

$$\cos(r-m)x = \cos rx \cos mx + \sin rx\sin mx,$$
for any $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = (s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)$. Then we can write your problem as,

\begin{align}
\max\ & x^{T}Mx \\
s.t.&\ 0 \leq x \leq s
\end{align}

where in inequality holds component wise and the $i$th row and $j$th column of $M$ is, $M_{ij} = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi (i-j)}{n}\right)$